# Does the position of legend tag within fieldset matter?

Tags: html, w3c

I have a fieldset as below:

```
<fieldset>
    <legend>Colour</legend>
    <label><input type="radio" name="colour" value="blue"> Blue </label>
    <label><input type="radio" name="colour" value="red"> Red </label>
</fieldset>
```

Here if I keep the `legend` tag below all the `label` tags, the HTML renders the `fieldset` exactly same as before.

```
<fieldset>
    <label><input type="radio" name="colour" value="blue"> Blue </label>
    <label><input type="radio" name="colour" value="red"> Red </label>
    <legend>Colour</legend>
</fieldset>
```

Even this renders the same.

So question here is, whether it is programmatically correct and as per standards to write legend tag at any place within `fieldset`.

Comment: http://checker.html5.org

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> So question here is, whether it is programmatically correct and as per standards to write legend tag at any place within `fieldset`.

No, it is not. The `legend` element (if present) **must** be the first child of a `fieldset` element.

---

This is what the [HTML5 spec.](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/form-elements.html#the-fieldset-element) says:

> **4.10.15 The `fieldset` element**
>   [...]
>
> **[Content model](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/dom.html#content-models):**
>
> Optionally a [`legend`](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/form-elements.html#the-legend-element) element, followed by [flow content](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/dom.html#flow-content-2).

---

The [HTML4.01 spec.](https://www.w3.org/TR/html4/interact/forms.html#edef-FIELDSET) defines the `fieldset` element as follows:

> ```
> <!ELEMENT FIELDSET - - (#PCDATA,LEGEND,(%flow;)*) -- form control group -->
> ```

where the comma-separated list defines the order in which the child elements must appear, i.e. `LEGEND` has to appear before other flow (block or inline) elements.